# Best way to join 3 lists and count how many times an ID is in the list using linq

Tags: c#, linq

Looking for some help with this problem i'm trying to work through to learn how linq works. 
My thinking was to join the person and customer list on personID to get the name for the customers and then join the customer and sale lists on customerID and then count the customerID in sale to get the amount of sales by the customer that were from the online store.

Task: Determine which people have placed the most orders from our online store

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string PersonType { get; set; }
    public bool NameStyle { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Suffix { get; set; }
}

public class Sale
{
    public int SalesOrderId { get; set; }
    public int RevisionNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ShipDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsOnlineOrder { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int? SalesPersonId { get; set; } 
    public int? TerritoryID { get; set; }
    public decimal SubTotal { get; set; }
    public decimal TaxAmt { get; set; }
    public decimal Freight { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalDue { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    //CustomerID can belong to a store or a person
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public int? StoreID { get; set; }
    public int? PersonID { get; set; }
    public int? TerritoryID { get; set; }
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
}

    public void MostOrders()
    {
        List<Person> per = Data.GetAllPersons();
        List<Sale> sale = Data.GetAllSales();
        List<Customer> cus = Data.GetAllCustomers();

        var join = (from x in per
                    join y in cus
                    on x.PersonID equals y.PersonID
                    join t in sale
                    on y.CustomerID equals t.CustomerId
                    select new
                    {
                        ......
                    });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a class that will hold gather all "store entities" and their sales, i think that using a collection of this class (`StoreEntity` in my example) it will be much easier to perform a variety of data manipulation (for this task and in future tasks).
here is my suggestion:

```
public class StoreEntity
{
    Person PersonEntity { get; set; }
    Customer CustomerEntity { get; set; }
    List<Sale> SalesList { get; set; }

    public StoreEntity(Person p, Customer c,List<Sale> sales)
    {
        this.PersonEntity = p;
        this.CustomerEntity = c;
        this.SalesList = sales;
    }

    public int SalesCount
    {
        get
        {
            if (SalesList == null)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                return SalesList.Count;
            }
        }
    }
}

public List<StoreEntity> Entities { get; set; }
public void MostOrders()
{
    List<Person> per = Data.GetAllPersons();
    List<Sale> sale = Data.GetAllSales();
    List<Customer> cus = Data.GetAllCustomers();

    Entities = new List<StoreEntity>();
    foreach (Person p in per)
    {
        var cust = cus.Where(x => x.PersonID == p.PersonID).Select(x => x).SingleOrDefault();
        if (cust != null)
        {
            var sales = sale.Where(x => x.CustomerId == cust.CustomerID).ToList();
            StoreEntity entity = new StoreEntity(p, cust, sales);
            Entities.Add(entity);
        } 
    }

    // now you have list of all entities with their sales
    // it will be musch easy to manipulate with linq
    // you can do this:
    Entities = Entities.OrderBy(x => x.SalesCount).ToList();
    // or this...
    var bestEntity = Entities.Max(x => x.SalesCount);
}
```